# Objective-C / Cocoa: What is the "Application" proxy object in Interface Builder / Nib good for?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Does someone have a easy-to-understand example what this Application object is good for? Why is it there? And in what cases do I need it?

Answer (score 3):

It's a pointer to the shared NSApplication object. See the class reference for everything NSApplication can do, but basically the reason you see it in your IB window is so you can easily set the delegate to your controller object, and hook up menu commands like terminate:.